# ESP8266 WiFi signal strength

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno, at-command, esp8266

how to use AT+CWLAP in esp8266 to get wifi signal strength? I want to get the signal strength which is displayed on the serial monitor and use it in my code in arduino IDE!

Comment: You send the command and then read the response.

Answer (score 0):

After sending the AT+CWLAP command, ESP8266 will answer with a list of all available AP's detected.

The format of the response will be like:

`+CWLAP:<ecn>,<ssid>,<rssi>,<mac>,<freq offset,<freq calibration>`

where:

`<ecn>: indicates the security level, from 0 (OPEN) to 4 (Maximum security level)`

`<ssid>: it's the ssid of the AP`

`<rssi>: it's the signal strength, which is indicated in decibel format (e.g. -70)`

`<mac>: it's the MAC address`

`<ch>: channel`

`<freq offset>: ut's the frequency offset of AP，unit：KHz.`

`<freq calibration>: it's the calibration for frequency offset`

So, the `<rssi>` parameter is what you are interested in.

Maybe, depending on the firmware version of your ESP8266, it's possible that AT+CWLAP command returns a different number of parameters, omitting, for example, the last four.